# Serializing/Deserializing JSON?

Tags: amazon-ion

I'm new to using ION so please excuse the probably simple question. In looking at the one of the cookbook samples provided in the [documentation](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/guides/cookbook.html)...

```
let ion = require('ion-js');

let unformatted = '{level1: {level2: {level3: "foo"}, x: 2}, y: [a,b,c]}';

let reader = ion.makeReader(unformatted);
let writer = ion.makePrettyWriter();
writer.writeValues(reader);
writer.close();
console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, writer.getBytes()));
```

Can ION take in a JSON object as opposed to a string? Doing something like the below where I change the *unformatted* variable from a string to a JSON object results in zero bytes from the writer...

```
let ion = require('ion-js');

let unformatted = {level1: {level2: {level3: "foo"}, x: 2}, y: [a,b,c]};

let reader = ion.makeReader(unformatted);
let writer = ion.makePrettyWriter();
writer.writeValues(reader);
writer.close();
console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, writer.getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, object = JSON.parse(string) and string = JSON.stringify(object) is what you are looking for. However your JSON is malformed in the example, and should not use variables:

```
{"level1":{"level2":{"level3":"foo"},"x":2},"y":[1,2,3]}
```

Assuming a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, for example, if you mean texts a, b, c, then:

```
{"level1":{"level2":{"level3":"foo"},"x":2},"y":["a","b","c"]}
```

Once made this:

```
JSON.stringify({"level1":{"level2":{"level3":"foo"},"x":2},"y":["a","b","c"]});
```

and

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse("{\"level1\":{\"level2\":{\"level3\":\"foo\"},\"x\":2},\"y\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]}"));
```

Are equivalent.

Comment: JSON.parse/JSON.stringify are obvious solutions, however they sort of defeat the purpose of using ION in my opinion. JSON.parse/JSON.stringify are slow for large objects/strings which is where I was under the impression ION would solve...

Comment: JSON.parse and JSON.stringify are the native implementations for those conversions. Probably they are the fastest and safest alternatives.

Comment: Of course you can use ION because other matters, probably because you are using ION on backend ( http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/guides/why.html ).Other thing that I didn't understand is that it seem you are talking about ION as a JSON library... but ION is other serialization language. Your question's title confused me a bit.

Comment: I see, I guess I was assuming with ION having a JavaScript implementation they were also providing a faster (i.e., faster than native browser) serialization/deserialization of JSON strings/objects with the ION structure being JSON-friendly...